Magento 2 pagebuilder module issue changes in slick.js not reflecting in frontend while minify js enabled
I am using adobe commerce cloud and inside app/design magento_pagebuilder i can see slick.js and slick.min.js i am making changes in slick.js and after deployment file slick.js not found inside pub/static folder and changes are reflecting.
Can anyone help me on this.

Have you any Cloudflare or caching system on site? try to once in pub/static's slick js with ? no-cache and check updated js reflect or not.
